# What shape is this, and how can i achieve it using css?

Tags: html, css

if anyone can help me with this it'd be great! What shape is this and do you have any ideas as to how i can achieve this shape in css?

[image]

EDIT:
I've managed to solve the management of trapezoids with the following jquery:

```
        function unassignTrap(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        $('.trapezoid').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('trapezoid');
            $(this).addClass('trapezoid2');
        })
        $(obj).removeClass('trapezoid2');
        $(obj).addClass('trapezoid');
    }
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I don't know if I understood well the question...about the shape... right trapezoid [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid]. About the css, what do you want to do specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be (some form of) a **trapezoid** and it's easy in CSS when you are using the `border` element.

```css
.trapezoid {
  border-bottom: 50px solid lightblue;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 80px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trapezoid"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy thanks for the answer, lets say i have 3 of them 2 are greyed and 1 is active in a list of tabs, how can i make the trapezoid adapt to them using jquery or js?

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a skewed rectangular div. You can achieve it by using the following code :

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: .5;
}

#skew {
    margin-left:50px;
    -ms-transform: skewX(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(45deg); 
    transform: skewX(45deg); 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div>
Normal Element.
</div>
<br>
  <br>
<div id="skew">
  skewed 45 degrees along the X-axis.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create this with `:after`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #55C7E3;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #55C7E3;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Here is example of tabs with this shape

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E3E4E6;
  margin-right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 30px 0 0 30px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #E3E4E6;
}
li.active {
  background: #55C7E3;
}
li.active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #55C7E3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Lorem ipsum.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks nenad, however i used parts from Roy's answer and also wrote my own jquery func to do the handling of the traps.